# Database trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

I have no experience in writing database trigger but I need one in my current project.

My use case is the following. I have two tables - Table 1 and Table 2.

These tables have a 1 : m relation.

My usecase is, if all records in Table1 have "VALUE2" than value in Table2 should updated to VALUE2.
So if record-value with ID 3 of table1 is updated to VALUE2 than Value of table2 also should be updated to value2.

It would be great if someone could help me - Thanks a lo for than!

**TABLE1**:

```
ID    FK_Table2        VALUE
-----------------------------
1        77           VALUE2
2        77           VALUE2
3        77           VALUE1
4        54           OTHERVALUE
```

**TABLE2**:

```
ID       VALUE
---------------
77       VALUE1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  What database is this for?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things like triggers are **highly** vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: It may be that this question is simplified, but you could easily use a query, rather than have the second table.  Something like `SELECT FK_TABLE2, VALUE FROM TABLE1 WHERE VALUE='VALUE2';`  In cases where needed, you could use this query as a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to learn and try [basic trigger](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_triggers.htm) first.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name 
AFTER UPDATE ON TABLE1
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
      /* trigger code goes here...*/
      /* for this particular case you need to update value of table2 */
      UPDATE TABLE2 SET VALUE = new.VALUE WHERE TABLE2.ID = new.FK_Table2 ;


END
```

Try and write some code. IF stucked... come back and let us know...

Answer (score 0):

No matter which system, there are some basic rules or best practices you should know. One is that it is bad form (and outright prohibited in many systems) for a trigger to reach back out and query the very table the trigger is written for. Your use case requires the trigger on Table1 to go back out and read from Table1 during the Update operation. Not good.

One available option is to use a stored procedure to handle all the updates to this table. They are more awkward to work with (for example: if a parameter is NULL, does that mean put a NULL in the corresponding field or leave it unmodified?). For that reason, and with the understanding that this is based on the limited amount of information in the question, I would recommend one of two alternatives.

One is to have a stored procedure that is used only to change the `VALUE` field. That field is not changed in a vacuum, but as part of a larger process. The step in the process that actually ends up changing the field could then call the SP.

Another is to front the table with a view with an "instead of" trigger and perform all DML through the view. This is the method I prefer, at least on those systems that allow triggers on views. The view trigger may query the underlying table as needed.

As for the logic (SP or trigger) here is some pseudo code:

```
-- Make the update
update table1 set value = @somevalue
 where id = @someid;
-- Get the group that id is in
select FK_Table2 into @somegroupid
  from Table1
 where id = @someid;
-- Are all the values in that group the same?
select count(*) into @OtherValues
  from Table1
 where FK_Table2 = @somegroupid
   and value <> @somevalue;
-- If so, notify the other table.
if @OtherValues = 0 then
    update table2 set value = @somevalue
     where id = @somegroupid;
```

I hope this answers your immediate question. However, based on what you have shown us here, the major cause of the problem would seem to be poor design. Let us know the higher level requirement you are trying to fill here and I'll bet we could come up with some modeling changes that would make this a whole lot easier without having to get really clever with SPs or triggers.